# Strange time format with microtime on Apache/IIS on Windows

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $start = microtime(true);
    $end = microtime(true);
    echo $end - $start;
?>
```

Why does this code produce results like:

```
1.1920928955078E-5,
5.9604644775391E-6,
6.9141387939453E-6
```

What does E-5 and E-6 mean?

And why is the difference so big? From 1.2 sec to 6.9 sec?

Comment: The largest result you gave was 11.92 microsecond and the smallest was 5.96 microsecond ... a difference of only about 6 microseconds.

Answer (score 6):

E is [scientific](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) or exponential notation where each number is represented as `a x 10`<sup>b</sup>, so `aEb` means to multiply by `a` by 10<sup>b</sup>.  So when b = -5, then you multiply by 10<sup>-5</sup> (same as dividing by 10<sup>5</sup>) or move the decimal place 5 places to the left.  When b is positive, then move the decimal place that many places to the right.  Note that in scientific notation there is always a single digit to the left of the decimal.

So

1.1920928955078E-5 = 0.000011920928955078

5.9604644775391E-6 = 0.0000059604644775391

6.9141387939453E-6 = 0.0000069141387939453

The differences are actually very small - a few microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

E is a scientific notation. E-x means that there are a certain amount of zeroes infront of the result you got.

Check out [this table](http://www.simetric.co.uk/siprefix.htm) to see what each result means.

In your example, you have 1,0E-6 which is 0,000001 which is Micro.

Answer (score 1):

1.1920928955078E-5 means 1.1920928955078 * 10^-5 == 0.000011920...

So your difference is:

0,000011920
0,000005960
0,000006914

So its within a factor of ~2 not ~6